# Fairly recent SF novel set in the near future, Alcoholics Anonymous is involved

Tags: story-identification, novel

I leafed through an SF novel a few years ago and put it down.  And now I wish I hadn't.  What I remember about it was that it was fairly modern (written maybe 90s or later), rather longish, written with fairly complex prose, was a near-future story, and somehow or another it involved Alcoholic Anonymous.  :)  I remember that its writer got reviews from the critics that were generally better than what a sci-fi writer gets.  In some circles he is even considered a "Serious Writer".  Anyone have any idea what this novel might have been?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Can you be more specific about "a few years ago"?  A year range is better, especially if this question doesn't attract potential answers right away.  Check out the other [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407), they might help you recall additional details you can [edit] into your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If anyone is interested, another bit of extremely roundabout sleuthing (You can find anything on the internet if your search path is wild enough.) and I got it.  It is *Infinite Jest* by David Foster Wallace.  It might be argued whether it is science fiction, it seems.  The critics might classify it as more of a "magical realism" kind of thing.  But it looks interesting, whatever they call it.  Thanks.

Comment: What was the search path that worked for you?

Comment: And, it looks like you have some general Stack Overflow experience, but don't forget to self-accept in 48 hours.

Comment: I remembered it being mentioned in First Things (a print and online mag about politics, philosophy, literature, etc. from a mainly Christian [and largely but not exclusively Catholic] perspective).  So I went there and searched "science fiction" but nothing showed up.  Then I searched "science fiction anonymous" and saw a line that rang a bell.  The article was about another article about David Foster Wallace.  I went there, nothing specific.  So I went Amazon and searched for the author's name.  I recognized the cover immediately.  "Around my elbow to get to my thumb," as my mom used to say.

Comment: I found this bit of blurb which, with it being set in the near future,  is enough IMO to class  it as science fiction....."Infinite Jest is set in a near future in which the Gregorian calendar has been supplanted by a sponsorship arrangement. Most of the action of the novel takes place in the Year of the Depend Adult Undergarment [Depend is a real brand of adult nappies]."

Comment: I'm somewhat startled to find that I actually have this as an ebook, and have owned it for about two years, I might try to read it someday!

Comment: I just have to chuckle at a description of _Infinite Jest_ that includes the line "rather longish, written with fairly complex prose.."

Comment: Having read Infinite Jest - "long" I would agree with. But only longISH? The book's as long as "War and Peace"!

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Is there any particular reason for the "in 48 hours"? I know I answered and accepted once of my own SO questions a lot longer after posting the question.

Comment: @AlexM Well, I have been told that I have a bit of a gift for understatement.  Just a bit.  :)  In my own defense, it had actually been some years since I saw the book and my memory was a little (!) hazy.